# R - Create a nested JSON object with two names from two different dataframes

Tags: json, r, jsonlite

Having two dataframes like

**final_data2:**

```
      id type lang div
1   hola page   es   1
```

and **paths:**

```
  source target count
1   hola  adios     1
```

I am able to combine both dataframes in the same JSON using `jsonlite` and the following code:

```
cat(toJSON(c(apply(final_data2,1,function(x)list(id = unname(x[1]), 
type = unname(x[2]), lang = unname(x[3]), div = unname(x[4]))),
apply(paths,1,function(x)list(source = unname(x[1]), target = unname(x[2]),
playcount = unname(x[3])))), pretty = TRUE))
```

The result is a set of arrays as following:

```
[
  {
    "id": ["hola"],
    "type": ["page"],
    "lang": ["es"],
    "div": ["1"]
  },
  {
    "source": ["hola"],
    "target": ["adios"],
    "playcount": ["1"]
  }
]
```

However, I need that the generated object contains two names (`nodes` and `links`), each nesting one of the previously defined dataframes. Therefore, the structure should look like this:

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {
        "id": ["hola"],
        "type": ["page"],
        "lang": ["es"],
        "div": ["1"]
    }
  ],
  "links": [
    {
        "source": ["hola"],
        "target": ["adios"],
        "playcount": ["1"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Any tip on how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the data.frames as a named list into `toJSON`:

```
library(jsonlite)

df1 <- read.table(textConnection("      id type lang div
1   hola page   es   1"), header = T)
df2 <- read.table(textConnection("  source target count
1   hola  adios     1"), header = T)


toJSON(list(nodes = df1, links = df2), pretty = T)
# {
# "nodes": [
#   {
#     "id": "hola",
#     "type": "page",
#     "lang": "es",
#     "div": 1
#   }
#   ],
# "links": [
#   {
#     "source": "hola",
#     "target": "adios",
#     "count": 1
#   }
#   ]
# }
```

Comment: So simple that I can only shame on me :) Thx, it worked like a charm